# how to insert imagebutton to linkbutton is it a bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

i try to add image button to link button but how to do that below codes not working?

```
  ImageButton _btnSave = new ImageButton();
            _btnSave.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _btnSave.AlternateText = "fsfsf";
            _btnSave.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btnSave_Click);
            _btnSave.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            _btnSave.ImageUrl = "~/images/Ok.png";

            LinkButton btnSave = new LinkButton();
            btnSave.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            PlhControl.Controls.Add(_btnSave);
            btnSave.Text = "Test";
            btnSave.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click);
            PlhControl.Controls.Add(btnSave);
```

Comment: I think you meant to ask `why insert an imagebutton to a linkbutton?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't insert ImageButton into LinkButton, you should just add Image instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to insert a `LinkButton` into an `ImageButton`. Both controls essentially do the same thing; they just look different.

What you can do is put an image inside of a LinkButton, which would basically make it an `ImageButton`, aside from a few key differences (submit behavior):

```
LinkButton btnSave = new LinkButton(); 
btnSave.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  
btnSave.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); 
btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click); 

Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "someimage.png";
btnSave.Controls.Add(img);

PlhControl.Controls.Add(btnSave);
```